# Google Analytics: how to track clicks on link in extern campagin

Tags: google-analytics

In a scenario where a website URL is linked into a newsletter, how can I track how many clicks that URL gets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **UTM parameters** in querystring to track how many sessions are generated from that source.

Here a tool that allows you to easily add campaign parameters to URLs so you can measure Custom Campaigns in Google Analytics: https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/campaign-url-builder/

You can hang them on any url leading to your website regardless of the type of campaign.

Comment: Hi! Can I use this also if the campaign is not sent using Google Ads but an external tool?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer.

Comment: Many thanks! I have a question: the tool you sent me is just for developing? I am asking because it's called Demo and Tools ... or the link that generates are the effective and workings?

Comment: You're welcome, the link generated is working. Mark answer as solved, please.